# How to convert python dictionary to upload agent to Dialogflow?

Tags: python, json, dialogflow-es

I'm new to dialogflow, trying to convert python dictionary like

`dict = {"Monday": "running","Tuesday": "swimming","Wednesday": "cycling"}`

to upload agent to Dialogflow.

From Dialogflow it said that: The folders should contain JSON files of the intents and entities

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your dict about entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of keys in the agent.json that need to be filled. The best place to find the parameters would be the Dialogflow documentation i.e https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent-json-fields

In order to create an agent. You can import a zip file. The structuring of the folders of the zip file looks as follows:

```
-main (folder)
 - intents (folder)
   - a.json (intent json file)
   - b.json (intent json file)
 - entities (folder)
   - x.json (entity json file)
   - y.json (entity json file)
 - agent.json
 -package.json
```

I hope this helps you structure your JSON files.